# Reports with parameter working fine independently but not functional in cockpit (composite document)

Tags: highcharts, birt, dashboard, spagobi

I am a newbie and using spagobi 5.2. 
I created PI highchart and birt report. 
They are working fine standalone with parameter.

But when I am trying to put them in cockpit they are not working as expected. 
I notice two things :

1) Highchart Pie in composit showing a dialogue box - 'Execution Analytical Drivers'

2) PI chart could not able to pass the parameter to the BIRT report in composit document

[image: highchart asking for parameter in composite document]

Following is the composit document details :

```
<DOCUMENTS_COMPOSITION template_value="/jsp/engines/documentcomposition/template/dynamicTemplate.jsp">  
    <DOCUMENTS_CONFIGURATION video_width="1200" video_height="1064">  
        <DOCUMENT sbi_obj_label="chartHighJobDesc" local_file_name="chartHighJobDesc.sbichart">  
            <PARAMETERS>  
                <PARAMETER type="OUT" sbi_par_label="param1" default_value="na" id="1">  
                    <REFRESH>  
                        <REFRESH_DOC_LINKED labelDoc="rptEmpJobDescription" labelParam="param1" typeCross="INTERNAL"/>  
                    </REFRESH>  
                </PARAMETER>  
            </PARAMETERS>  
            <STYLE style="position:absolute;margin:0px;left:0px;top:0px;width:390px;height:420px;" mode="auto"/>  
            <id>chartHighJobDesc</id>  
        </DOCUMENT>  
        <DOCUMENT sbi_obj_label="rptEmpJobDescription" local_file_name="rptEmpJobDescription.rptdesign">  
            <PARAMETERS>  
                <PARAMETER type="IN" sbi_par_label="param1" id="1">  
                    <REFRESH/>  
                </PARAMETER>  
            </PARAMETERS>  
            <STYLE style="position:absolute;margin:0px;left:0px;top:422px;width:990px;height:386px;" mode="auto"/>  
            <id>rptEmpJobDescription</id>  
        </DOCUMENT>  
    </DOCUMENTS_CONFIGURATION>  
</DOCUMENTS_COMPOSITION>
```

I have posted the same to spagobi forum as well at the following link : 
https://www.spagoworld.org/jforum/posts/list/4234.page

Thanks in advance for your kind help.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get the answer of my second query. After setting default value to birt report I found both the reports are in composit document and Hicharts (PI) able to send parameter to BIRT chart.

But still I am searching for the answer of the first query, i.e. Highchart PI in cockpit showing a dialogue box - 'Execution Analytical Drivers'. If anybody got a workaround it will be great.